# Finding count of documents grouped by Today, This Week , This Month

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using Redash to perform data visualization and I  have documents that have a structure like:

```
{
"id" : "12345",
"created_at" : "07/06/19 08:53"
},
{
"id" : "123456",
"created_at" : "07/06/19 12:13" 
},
{
"id" : "123457",
"created_at" : "06/06/19 20:18"
}
```

What I want as the result is

```
{
"TimeRange" : "today",
"count" : "6"
},
{
"TimeRange" : "this Week",
"count" : 15
},
{
"TimeRange" : "this Month",
"count" : 40
}
```

I can group by dates using

```
db.doc.aggregate([
     { $group: 
        { _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$created_at" } }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

But is there any way preferably using aggregations to display the result in different time ranges as specified?

Comment: There is.  One quick Q:   How many observations in the set?   If it is 1000 then the agg can be a little less clever.   If it is 10,000,000 then I have to assume indexing must be in place.

Comment: About 2-3 thousand observtions in the set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format here is particularly irksome because of the lack of century and month vs. day ambiguity.  It would be much better for you to store real datetimes so that date operations could be easily brought to bear against them.  But for this exercise let us assume you cannot.   The date functions in MongoDB avoid assumptions therefore there is no century-less `dateFromString` format component so we have to do it all ourselves.   OK.   Let's start with this set of data, similar to yours:

```
var r = [
         // Assume MM/DD/YY  where YY is 20YY
         // last week                                                           
         {"created_at" : "06/01/19 10:53"},

         // yesterday, this week                                                
         {"created_at" : "06/05/19 10:53"},

         // today                                                    
         {"created_at" : "06/06/19 08:53"},
         {"created_at" : "06/06/19 12:53"},
         {"created_at" : "06/06/19 18:33"},

         // tomorrow, this week                                                 
         {"created_at" : "06/07/19 19:33"},
         {"created_at" : "06/07/19 20:33"},

         // later, but this month                                               
         {"created_at" : "06/27/19 07:33"},
         {"created_at" : "06/27/19 08:33"},

         // next month                                                          
         {"created_at" : "07/04/19 11:33"},

         // next year                                                           
         {"created_at" : "07/04/20 11:33"}

    ];
```

To figure out today, this month, etc. we need to set a target date outside of the data we have stored.

```
today = new ISODate("2019-06-06");
target_week = 22;   // up to you to implement
target_mon = today.getMonth() + 1;   // MongoDB mon is 1-12, not 0-11
target_year = today.getFullYear();
```

Here is a solution.  We could shortcut and just use pieces of the date string but instead we will construct a real date which sets us up nicely to do things other than the specific requested grouping.  This means we will pull things out of the date after we put them into the date.

```
db.foo.aggregate([

// Create a real date from the pieces.  Ignore time bits for now:               
{ $addFields: {"rd":
  {$dateFromParts : {
        "year": {$add: [2000,{$toInt: {$substr: ["$created_at",6,2]}} ] },
        "month":  {$toInt: {$substr: ["$created_at",0,2]}},
        "day":    {$toInt: {$substr: ["$created_at",3,2]}}
    }}
  }}

// Now use facet to act as a "multigroup":                                      
,{$facet: {
  "today": [
{$match: { "rd": today}}, {$count: "n"}
           ]

  ,"This week": [
{$project: { "w": {$week: "$rd"}, "y": {$year: "$rd"} }}
,{$match: { "w": target_week, "y": target_year}}
,{$count: "n"}
                 ]

  ,"This month": [
{$project: { "m": {$month: "$rd"}, "y": {$year: "$rd"} }}
,{$match: { "m": target_mon, "y": target_year}}
,{$count: "n"}
                  ]
    }}

  ,"This year": [
{$project: { "y": {$year: "$rd"} }}
,{$match: { "y": target_year}}
,{$count: "n"}
                  ]
    }}

]);
```

which yields

```
{
    "today" : [
        {
            "n" : 3
        }
    ],
    "This week" : [
        {
            "n" : 6
        }
    ],
    "This month" : [
        {
            "n" : 9
        }
    ],
    "This year" : [
        {
            "n" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```